# bluetoothctl - can't pair device after removing it?

Tags: bluetooth, debian

I used **bluetoothctl** to pair a set of bluetooth enable hearing protectors. Since I need to do this programatically with a python script, I used the **remove** command to remove the device.

Now, I can't pair with the device again. If I turn on the headset with **bluetoothctl** running, I get the following:

```
[NEW] Device 1C:6E:4C:35:CC:D1 Peltor Sport 500
[CHG] Device 1C:6E:4C:35:CC:D1 Connected: no
[DEL] Device 1C:6E:4C:35:CC:D1 Peltor Sport 500
[NEW] Device 1C:6E:4C:35:CC:D1 Peltor Sport 500
[CHG] Device 1C:6E:4C:35:CC:D1 Connected: no
[DEL] Device 1C:6E:4C:35:CC:D1 Peltor Sport 500
[NEW] Device 1C:6E:4C:35:CC:D1 Peltor Sport 500
[CHG] Device 1C:6E:4C:35:CC:D1 Connected: no
[DEL] Device 1C:6E:4C:35:CC:D1 Peltor Sport 500
```

I've tried to connect and to pair:

```
[bluetooth]# pair 1C:6E:4C:35:CC:D1
Device 1C:6E:4C:35:CC:D1 not available

[bluetooth]#  pair 1C:6E:4C:35:CC:D1
Device 1C:6E:4C:35:CC:D1 not available
```

It seems like using the **remove** command is like saying "don't ever connect to this device again". Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you put the headset back into pairing mode?  Sometimes it helps to pair the device with another computer, then try again to pair with the one you want.

Comment: I did put it back into pairing mode but that didn't help. So, I paired it with my PC, disconnected it and tried it again using **bluetoothctl** and this time it worked. I would still like ot know if there is a way to solve this using **bluetoothctl***.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem, I solved it by simply scanning again :

```
bluetoothctl scan on
```